# Refreshing the div and my css layout is changing

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys i am refreshing the div but my layout is changing when the div is resfreshing i want to stop it when i remove this code my css works fine but when i remove it it gets abnormal.

**HTML**

```
                        <i class="icon-bell"></i>

                        <span class="badge bg-important">
                        <div id="response">
                        <?php 
                        $ans=0;
                        foreach($result as $rec){
                        $ans+=count($rec);
                        }
                        echo $ans;
                        ?>      
                          </div>                    
                        </span>

                </li>
```

**Javascript**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
    $('#response').load('<?php echo base_url().'adminsite/menutop';?>');
    }, 60 * 10);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably change the html structure and the css properties won't match anymore. Or maybe a missing closing tag in your include.

Well, anyway, for a concise answer, provide a little more informations about your code !